# How to make multiple spans in the same word hover together?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm very new to html and css, but I'm trying my best.
I have the word Google in a table row that has every letter in the word colored a different color, like the Google logo actually is. To do this, the only way I could think of was to `span` each letter a different color. That's all fine and good. What I would like to do is make it so that when you hover over the word Google, it changes to the specified hover color. The code I have works to do that, but it does it to each letter individually, because of the `span`s. I would like that when the word Google is hovered over, the entire word changes color and not just the individual letter that is being hovered over. Is there a way to connect all the `span`s so they act as one, or is there a better way of going about having different colors for each letter in the word Google?

Here is my relevant html code:

```
            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background: #88FAF8; border-color: black; letter-spacing: -2px">
                <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration: none">
                    <span style="color: blue">G</span>                  
                    <span style="color: red">o</span>
                    <span style="color: yellow">o</span>
                    <span style="color: blue">g</span>
                    <span style="color: green">l</span>
                    <span style="color: red">e</span>
                </a>
            </td>
```

and here is my relevant CSS code:

```
    td:hover {background: #000000 !important;}

    a:hover {color: #2BFBFB !important;}

    span:hover {color: #2BFBFB !important;}
```

The `a:hover` is for other cells that don't have the span code in them. the `span:hover` is for the Google cell because `a:hover` doesn't work on it due to the `span`s, but like I've said, it doesn't work exactly like I would like it to.

Forgive me if my posting isn't formatted exactly right. This is my first post. I'll get it right.

Here's my code in action at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sharkie405/36aT7/

Comment: Welcome to SO :) In future, it's good to copy your code into a live editor like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that people can easily see your issue and edit your code, update it, and give it back to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `a:hover span` to cover all the `span`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/r44zw/

```
a:hover span {
    color: #2BFBFB !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have learned classes yet, but this seems like a good case for it. You may want to add a class to you anchor tag (a tag) like so. `class="google-link"` or so you can see it with all the other code.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" class="google" style="text-decoration: none">
  <span style="color: blue">G</span>                  
  <span style="color: red">o</span>
  <span style="color: yellow">o</span>
  <span style="color: blue">g</span>
  <span style="color: green">l</span>
  <span style="color: red">e</span>
</a>
```

then you could add a `.google:hover` rule to your css

```
.google:hover span{
  color: #CCC !important;
}
```

adding the class will ensure if you ever have another span inside an a it won't get the google hover color.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHr9L/)

Using `!important` inside the `.google:hover span` rule is necessary here to override the high precedence of inline styles. styles with !important have an added value that makes it higher than an inline-style. (More about [specificity/precedence](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) here, but keep in mind that's a somewhat advanced css topic.)

### Edit:

Using !important is also somewhat bad practice and usually avoidable, although it is necessary in some cases. I would suggest avoiding it when possible, here is the way to do it without !important.

html (almost the same but now it has classes on each span).

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" class="google" style="text-decoration: none">
  <span class="text-blue">G</span>                  
  <span class="text-red">o</span>
  <span class="text-yellow">o</span>
  <span class="text-blue">g</span>
  <span class="text-green">l</span>
  <span class="text-red">e</span>
</a>
```

css (a color added for each class)

```
.google:hover span{
  color: #CCC !important;
}

.text-blue {
    color: blue;
}

.text-red {
    color: red;
}

.text-yellow {
    color: yellow;
}

.text-green {
    color: green;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHr9L/1/)

Comment: I am familiar with classes. I tried your method and it also worked. Thank you for the information on the `!important` usages. There seems to be so many different ways to accomplish the same task, I'm often not sure which is the best route. It's always good to learn "best practices".

Comment: Hey, no problem glad I could give some insight, that article on specificity is definitely worth the read if you're going to be doing a lot of web development. Knowing specificity can save you a lot of headaches later on. You don't have to read it though since I said it's kind of advanced, but nothing too hard if you really want to learn it.