# How to get entire element to change color

Tags: html, css

In the snippet below, I want the entire div to be highlighted when I hover over it, not individual words. There is probably an easy way to do it, I just can't figure it out at the moment.

I've tried putting all the elements separately and together with no luck. If possible, I want to do it using CSS only. I don't want to use JavaScript unless it's absolutely necessary.

```css
.StepList { 
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
}  
.stepBox { 
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
.listNumbers { 
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px; /* or 50% */
  border-radius: 15px; /* or 50% */
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.locations {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #dedede;
}
.typeOfBuild {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #dedede;
}
/*hover for step list*/
a.stepBox:hover .StepList:hover, .stepBox:hover, .locations:hover, .typeOfBuild:hover {
  color: #6495a9;
} 
.listNumbers:hover {
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: #6495a9;
}
```

```html
<div class = "StepList">
  <span class ="stepBox"> 
    <span class = "activeAccommodation">
      <a href ="#">
        <span class ="listNumbers"> 1 </span>
        <span class="locations">location </span>
        <span class="typeOfBuild">Accommodation </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    </span>
    <span class = "stepBox">
      <span class = "activeActivities">
      <a href ="#">
        <span class ="listNumbers">2</span>
        <span class="locations">location</span>
        <span class="typeOfBuild">Activities</span>
      </a>
    </span>
    </span>
      <span class = "stepBox">
      <span class = "activeRestaurant">
      <a href ="#">
        <span class ="listNumbers">3</span>
        <span class="locations">location</span>
        <span class="typeOfBuild">Restaurants</span>
      </a>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span class = "stepBox">
      <span class = "activeNighlife">
      <a href ="#">
        <span class ="listNumbers">4</span>
        <span class="locations">location</span>
        <span class="typeOfBuild">Nightlife </span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031460/how-to-make-multiple-spans-in-the-same-word-hover-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have separate highlighting rules for `.listNumbers`, `.locations`, and `.typeOfBuild`. If you want all of these to be activated when the user hovers over a `.StepList`, write the following:

```
.StepList:hover .listNumbers, .StepList:hover .locations, .StepList:hover .typeOfBuild {
    color: #6495a9;   
}
```

This is demonstrated in the following snippet. Click on the "Run code snippet" button below to see the result.

```css
.StepList {
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
}  
.stepBox {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 110%;
} 
.listNumbers {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px; /* or 50% */
  border-radius: 15px; /* or 50% */
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.locations {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #dedede;
}
.typeOfBuild {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #dedede;
}

/* link styling */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background: #ffc;
}

/* container hover */
.StepList:hover .listNumbers, .StepList:hover .locations, .StepList:hover .typeOfBuild {
  color: #6495a9;
}
```

```html
<div class = "StepList">
  <span class ="stepBox"> 
    <span class = "activeAccommodation">
      <a href ="#">
        <span class ="listNumbers"> 1 </span>
        <span class="locations">location </span>
        <span class="typeOfBuild">Accommodation </span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class = "stepBox">                  
    <span class = "activeActivities">
      <a href ="#">
        <span class ="listNumbers">2</span>
        <span class="locations">location</span>
        <span class="typeOfBuild">Activities</span>
      </a>                  
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class = "stepBox">
    <span class = "activeRestaurant">
      <a href ="#">
        <span class ="listNumbers">3</span>
        <span class="locations">location</span>
        <span class="typeOfBuild">Restaurants</span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class = "stepBox">
    <span class = "activeNighlife">
      <a href ="#">
        <span class ="listNumbers">4</span>
        <span class="locations">location</span>
        <span class="typeOfBuild">Nightlife </span>
      </a>                  
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I also modified the link styling to make the page look less cluttered.

Comment: ya, it's more less what I wanted, with the yellow background anyway. I did it a different way, by changing opacity of the div when I hover over it, It works perfect now

Comment: Oh, good! I'm glad to hear it. You now have enough reputation to upvote answers, so if you can do that too, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/85543qak/1/)

What i've done is, When you hover on the `StepList` div, the whole div gets highlighted with a red background

I've added this to your CSS

```
.StepList:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```